# Images not loading in site hosted on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to host my site on Google APP Engine. I have configured my app.yaml file and deployed the website. All the files deployed correctly including the css and js files. What I am facing trouble with are the image files. I am getting a 404 resource not found error in my console for the images that my static web page is using. I am not sure what the problem is. Here is the structure of my site

```
index.html
view(folder)
   -images
       -abc.png
       -xyz.png
   -js
   -css
```

Here is the code in app.yaml

```
- url: /(.*\.png)
mime_type: image/png
static_files: template/\1
upload: template/(.*\.png)
```

Wanted to know if the app.yaml is configured correctly to go through the images folder and then upload my image files.

Comment: After hours of trying different things, I finally got it tow ork by using this

    - url: /view/images
      mime_type: image/png   
      static_files: /view/images/**.png
      upload: (.*\.png)

GAEfan's answer is useful as well and that should work too.

Comment: did it work for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pointing to the `template` directory in app.yaml, but you images are actually in a directory tree branched as `view/images`.  Try this:

```
- url: /(.*\.png)
mime_type: image/png
static_files: view/images/\1
upload: view/images/(.*\.png)
```

Comment: Did this solution worked for you @Vinay Gaba?